# Module pattern's anonymous closures

Tags: javascript

In every article about module pattern I see defining modules in a following way:

```
var foobar = (function() {
   // code
})();
```

What is the difference between this and:

```
var foobar = function() {
   // code
};
```

? Both seem to be working in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, `foobar` returns the result of the anonymous function call, whereas in the second one `foobar`*IS* the anonymous function.

This all means they aren't the same thing at all, and dont work the same way.

Answer (score 3):

They shouldn't seem to be working the same way.

One defines a function and calls it, one defines a function.

In the first case, `foobar` is set to whatever the function returns.

In the second, `foobar` *is* the function.